# Code to add element to the beginning of a list in c - what's the error?

Tags: c, list, pointers, singly-linked-list

I'm told that this will fail to correctly add the node to the list but I've tested it and it seems to work. Can anyone let me know what's incorrect in this code?

```
struct node {
   int num;
   struct node* next;
};

void add_first(struct node* head, struct node* new_node) {
   new_node->next = head;
   head = new_node;
}
```

The exact question I'm trying to answer is:

a) This function will fail to give the expected result (i.e., add the node). What is the problem and when does it occur?

To try and find the issue, I've created four nodes, used the add_first function on them and then displayed the results. I seem to get correct output, though. Here's the program I wrote overall, not including the above functions:

```
void display(struct node* head) {
    printf("%d   ", head->num);
    if(head->next == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    display(head->next);
}

int main() {
    struct node* n1;
    struct node* n2;
    struct node* n3;

    n1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    n2 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    n3 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));

    n1->num = 1;
    n2->num = 2;
    n3->num = 3;

    add_first(n1, n2);
    add_first(n2, n3);

    display(n3);

    return 0;
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

> 3   2   1

Which seems to be correct. So, if I'm getting the correct output, why will the function fail to give the expected result? I don't see a problem in it.

Comment: The majar problem is that you can not update the caller's node. Try change API to like `n1 = add_first(n1, n2);` (return head) And other problem is `sizeof(struct node*)` --> `sizeof(struct node)` and `next` is not initialized. E.g `n1->num = 1;` --> `n1->num = 1; n1->next = NULL;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function and the test-program are incorrect.

The node `n1` shall be the head shall not it? However you are displaying the list passing the node `n3` instead of the head that is instead of the node `n1`.

In fact you built a list the head of which is `n3` and n2 and n1 are added to the tail of the list.

The problem with the function

```
void add_first(struct node* head, struct node* new_node) {
   new_node->next = head;
   head = new_node;
}
```

is that the pointer to the node `head` is passed by value. So this statement

```
head = new_node;
```

deals with a copy of the original head `n1`. In fact the function does not change `n1`.

You have to pass the head that is `n1` by reference.

A correct code can look at least like

```
void add_first( struct node **head, struct node *new_node ) 
{
   new_node->next = *head;
   *head = new_node;
}
```

Take into account that you have to set the data member next of added nodes to NULL. That is in main you have to write for each created node

```
n1->num = 1;
n1->next = NULL;
n2->num = 2;
n2->next = NULL;
n3->num = 3;
n3->next = NULL;
```

The function itself will be called like

```
add_first( &n1, n2 );
```

and

```
add_first( &n1, n3 );
```

In this case the function display can be called correctly passing to it the actual head

```
display( n1 );
```

Take into account that statements like this

```
n1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
                                        ^^^^^
```

are invalid. Instead of pointers you have to allocate the nodes themselves that is

```
n1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node ));
                                        ^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was missing the fact that the function was dealing with a copy instead of the original value. Your explanation is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`add_first(node,NULL)` will erase the head pointer data and give you error .

and second case if head is NULL `add_first(NULL,node);`